# Is this NpgsqlConnection factory thread safe?

Tags: .net, thread-safety, npgsql

Is this code thread safe?

```
public static NpgsqlConnection getConnection()
{          
    NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    csb.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server"];
    csb.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
    csb.Pooling = true;
    csb.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"];
    csb.Port = Convert.ToInt32( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["port"]);
    csb.Enlist = true;
    //csb.Database = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["databaseName"];

    return new NpgsqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString);
}
```

I use this connection *everywhere*, but sometimes I get a `TimeoutException`.

> A timeout has occured. If you were establishing a connection, increase Timeout value in ConnectionString. If you were executing a command, increase the CommandTimeout value in ConnectionString or in your NpgsqlCommand object.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `csb`, and where is it defined?

Answer (score 4):

Answering your question, NpgsqlConnection isn't thread safe. You shouldn't share an NpgsqlConnection with multiple threads.

But regarding your exception, if you notice, you get it when you call the NpgsqlConnection.Open() method. And in your getConnection() method, you don't call Open. You are opening the connection somewhere else.

Now, to get this exception when you are opening a connection, you must have reached the maximum connection pool size. This means you may not have closed previous open connections.

You have to either call close or dispose in your NpgsqlConnection object to have it returned to the connection pool. If you let the NpgsqlConnection instance goes out of scope, it won't be returned to pool and will count as an used connection.

In order to check if this is your problem, you have two possibilities:

1. Disable connection pool. You will not get this exception anymore, but as you are not properly closing the connections, you may end up reaching the maximum connections allowed per database. This is a postgresql server parameter.
2. Call NpgsqlConnection.ClearPool or ClearAllPool in order to remove all connections from the pool.

Note that those two possibilities should only be used to check if you are having connection pool problems. If your application starts to work ok after you use one of those methods, your application still has problems which need to be fixed.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I updated to npgsql 2.0.13 beta and problem seems to be fixed. App havent crashed for 6 days and when it might did it wasnt from this. Monitoring connections never were more than pool size. I guess it was a bug ? Not sure...

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not thread safe, because csb is not local and likely not thread safe. Use a local csb. Check if ConfigurationManager is thread safe.

Instantiating the connection itself is thread safe, as other threads cannot "see" the instance. Your connection problems probably stem from somewhere else. You may want to try what was given as a hint in the error message.

Comment: `ConfigurationManager` should be OK in most sane scenarios

Comment: So csb could cause the problems ? Ok I'll try. Good hint. I have done for optimisation but it seems totally pointless as it would take less than nanosecond to create a class. http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilderMembers.html

Comment: ok i checked again and csb was local in my project. So problem is somehwere else